# .NET MAUI How to get the reference for the view within a ViewCell

Tags: maui

Code:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="TopicList" Grid.Row="1" SeparatorVisibility="None"
          RowHeight="70">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Tapped="Cell_OnTapped">
                <StackLayout Padding="20,0,20,20">
                    <Border StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 30" HeightRequest="50"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Border.Shadow>
                            <Shadow Opacity="0.5"
                                    Radius="3"
                                    Brush="Black"
                                    Offset="6,6" />
                        </Border.Shadow>
                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   FontSize="22"
                                   FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   Padding="15,0,0,0">
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How can I get the reference to the Grid from within Cell_OnTapped function ?

Tried:
1 - Enumerate children of the sender (ViewCell), but ViewCell is not a VisualObject and does not have descendants.

2 - I tried to move the tap to the label, that helped such that I can find the Grid as the sender's parent. However, label then does not accept taps unless the list item is separately selected. Not acceptable from a user experience point of view.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Directly manipulating the UI of templated controls is rarely a good idea.  That said, `ViewCell` has a `View` property containing its content

Comment: When the list item is tapped, I need to add a number of images into the grid. No intention to manipulate anything already on the template.

Comment: And yes, View property is the answer for my problem. I was too fixated to using `GetVisualTreeDescendants()`. Feel free to submit as an answer, or I can delete the question if it sounds too trivial.

Comment: Figured out other problem above I think. ViewCell comes with its own TapGestureRecognizer. And it seems to be defined even if Tapped is not set (and empty TapGestureRecognizer block. And when I add a second one things get confused.

Comment: To get further help, add to question your code attempt. Also put in question what you just said in that comment (so people don't have to read through the comments). And instead of "things get confused", say exactly what does or does not happen.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Respond to item selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview#respond-to-item-selection)?  It is not sure what you are doing on this ListView. Can you provide more information?